# get total attendance from Timesheet

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

in ower society, employee's payslip is based on timesheet attendance. so in order to make that possible, I have been changing in openerp(7) code, exactly in payroll.py
the previews code is based on" contract.working_hours " it takes the total of hours and it puts it in pyaslip.number_of_hours

```
def get_worked_day_lines(self, cr, uid, contract_ids, date_from, date_to, context=None):
    """
    @param contract_ids: list of contract id
    @return: returns a list of dict containing the input that should be applied for the given contract between date_from and date_to
    """
    def was_on_leave(employee_id, datetime_day, context=None):
        res = False
        day = datetime_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        holiday_ids = self.pool.get('hr.holidays').search(cr, uid, [('state','=','validate'),('employee_id','=',employee_id),('type','=','remove'),('date_from','<=',day),('date_to','>=',day)])
        if holiday_ids:
            res = self.pool.get('hr.holidays').browse(cr, uid, holiday_ids, context=context)[0].holiday_status_id.name
        return res

    res = []
    for contract in self.pool.get('hr.contract').browse(cr, uid, contract_ids, context=context):
        if not contract.working_hours:
            #fill only if the contract as a working schedule linked
            continue
        attendances = {
             'name': _("Normal Working Days paid at 100%"),
             'sequence': 1,
             'code': 'WORK100',
             'number_of_days': 0.0,
             'number_of_hours': 0.0,
             'contract_id': contract.id,
        }
        leaves = {}
        day_from = datetime.strptime(date_from,"%Y-%m-%d")
        day_to = datetime.strptime(date_to,"%Y-%m-%d")
        nb_of_days = (day_to - day_from).days + 1
        for day in range(0, nb_of_days):
            working_hours_on_day = self.pool.get('resource.calendar').working_hours_on_day(cr, uid, contract.working_hours, day_from + timedelta(days=day), context)
            if working_hours_on_day:
                #the employee had to work
                leave_type = was_on_leave(contract.employee_id.id, day_from + timedelta(days=day), context=context)
                if leave_type:
                    #if he was on leave, fill the leaves dict
                    if leave_type in leaves:
                        leaves[leave_type]['number_of_days'] += 1.0
                        leaves[leave_type]['number_of_hours'] += working_hours_on_day
                    else:
                        leaves[leave_type] = {
                            'name': leave_type,
                            'sequence': 5,
                            'code': leave_type,
                            'number_of_days': 1.0,
                            'number_of_hours': working_hours_on_day,
                            'contract_id': contract.id,
                        }
                else:
                    #add the input vals to tmp (increment if existing)
                    attendances['number_of_days'] += 1.0
                    attendances['number_of_hours'] += working_hours_on_day
        leaves = [value for key,value in leaves.items()]
        res += [attendances] + leaves
    return res
```

I'v been doing researche about how to browse and search a model,and what I want to do is get total from timesheet where hr_timeshet.employee_id = payslip.employee_id

```
def get_worked_day_lines(self, cr, uid, employee_id, date_from, date_to, context=None):
    res = []
    for sheet in self.pool.get('hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet').search(cr,uid, [('state','=','confirm'),('employee_id','=',employee_id)]):
        if not sheet:
            continue
        attendances = {
             'name': _("Normal Working Days paid at 100%"),
             'sequence': 1,
             'code': 'WORK100',
             'number_of_days': 0.0,
             'number_of_hours': 0.0,
             #'contract_id': contract.id,
        }
        leaves = {}
        day_from = datetime.strptime(date_from,"%Y-%m-%d")
        day_to = datetime.strptime(date_to,"%Y-%m-%d")
        nb_of_days = (day_to - day_from).days + 1
        for day in range(0, nb_of_days):
            if sheet:
                attendances['number_of_days'] += 1.0
                attendances['code'] = sheet.total_attendance
```

I really need that, thanks in advance
error:

> Invalid value hr.employee(1,) in domain term ('employee_id', '=', hr.employee(1,))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are getting the hr.employee object when you actually need only the id.
Try to change:

```
('employee_id','=',employee_id)]
```

to

```
('employee_id','=',employee_id.id)]
```

---

`sheet` is an integer, you must browse first the object and then access to `total_attendance`. 
Try:

```
if sheet:
    sheet_obj=self.pool.get('hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet').browse(cr, uid, sheet, context=context)
    attendances['number_of_days'] += 1.0
    attendances['code'] = sheet_obj.total_attendance
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks @Dayana but i got another error... 'int' object has no attribute 'total_attendance'

Comment: oooooh thank you thank you thank you, after a month you just solved a problem of a country.

Comment: ps: it didn't work when changing to `('employee_id','=',employee_id.id)` so I used  `('employee_id','=',employee_id)`

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you!